# Material Design progressdialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

```
 alertDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);                          
 alertDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loader));
 alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
 alertDialog.show();
```

Simply when I do this, green circle shows up with the word loading besides it. However when i DONT USE progress dialog, and i use a progressbar on the page I get a pink color as i have defined the below in my styles.xml

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/pink</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/pink</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/pink</item>
```

What is the solution of getting the circle pink color as in the progress bar on page?

Answer (score 11):

For API 21+ you can define the following style to colour the material progress dialog. Note that this should be under `values-v21` if you support lower platforms.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/MyAlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAlertDialog" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/pink</item>
</style>
```

`<item name="colorAccent">` is for AppCompat whereas `<item name="android:colorAccent">` is for API 21+. Material progress dialogs don't work with AppCompat, even with the new `v22.1` Support lib [AppCompatDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.html).

You can see Chris Banes' answer [here](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/#comment-1982923608) stating that he will not backport Progress Dialogs because they are "a bad pattern".

Comment: Fair comment that progress Dialog is a " bad pattern". Whats the suggested alternative?

Comment: @Zapnologica according to the developer guide: [_"However, if you need to indicate loading or indeterminate progress, you should instead follow the design guidelines for Progress & Activity and use a ProgressBar in your layout."_](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) instead of a `ProgressDialog`. So basically embed a `ProgressBar` somewhere and hide/unhide it as needed. I agree ProgressDialog tends to be a bad pattern (esp if non-cancelable), but I wish they would be more upfront and clear about it everywhere. Maybe even mention it in the ProgressDialog docs.

Comment: The link to a comment on Chris Banes' post now appears to be dead.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old, but if you are using AppCompat,
just add this attribute:

```
<item name="android:tint">@color/my_color_accent</item>
```

In your style

```
<style name="MaterialDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/my_color_accent</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me, these (and only these) style attributes were working:

```
<item name="android:indeterminateTint">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:progressTint">@color/colorAccent</item>
```