# Android ProgressDialog position issue and do we have Android's ProgressDialog from platform or support library?

Tags: android, material-design, progressdialog

I had this ProgressDialog working fine when my device was in 4.4.4 and I was not working on this app recently and device is upgraded to Lillipop mean while. I am not sure if this has caused anything to this issue but just mentioning.

**Question 1.** ProgressDialog shows on top left of the screen. See the attached pic. And below is the code. Also how to get transparent background ?

```
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_Alert);
    progressDialog.setTitle(title);
    progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString((R.string.progress_please_wait)));
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    progressDialog.show();
```

[image]

**Question 2.** I have gone through the material design docs and support docs. I could not find but is there any built in Material Designed ProgressDialog. Or we should depend on the libraries like https://github.com/rahatarmanahmed/CircularProgressView. ?

**EDIT :**
ClarkXP's answer, in fact more relevant, for another question mentioned below:
**Question 3.** I tried to use the [material-dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) but my gradle has thrown as error "Failed to resolve: compile com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.8.5.1".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526793/material-design-progressdialog

Answer (score 1):

To show progressDialogs with material design style, I use [Material-Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) library.

Greetings

**UPDATE**

The app build.gradle must have the next configuration for repositories and dependencies in the same file:

1. In Android closure:

   ```
   android {    
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
       ...[your configuration]
   }
   ```
2. And Repositories/Dependencies closure:

   ```
   repositories {
       maven {
           url "https://jitpack.io"
       }   
   }
   dependencies {   
       compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.1@aar'){
           transitive = true
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hello ClarkXP, thanks !
I tried to use it but I get "Failed to resolve ... 0.8.5.1" while gralde sync. Any clue on this ? I don't find an answer for this in github too. I tried JitPack repo too.

Comment: Can you post your app build.gradle file?

Comment: When I updated my Build tools 23.0.2, I get:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

I posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824788/processexception-when-buildtoolsversion-is-changed-from-22-0-1-to-23-0-1 long back but did not get any response:

Comment: @cgr please tell me if now works Material-Dialogs for you

Comment: Hi ClarkXP, yes it worked now and +1 for answer. ;-)

Comment: I could not do that because there is the first question that is not answered yet and that was my main question. So, it may confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

For 1),

This worked instead of the code in question:

```
mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, title, getResources().getString((R.string.progress_please_wait)), true);
```

I did not explore what difference it makes technically.